# Why does center_horizontally not center an element horizontally?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="00px"
        android:text="Slot1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/load"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start"
        android:text="Slot2" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/stat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/load"
        android:text="Slot3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and I expected the three boxes to be centered horizontally on the layout. But they are left-alignes. Why is that? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Gravity is used for placement of elements internal to the view (the text of the button).

Layout_gravity is used for LinearLayout and FrameLayout

layout_centerHorizontal, layout_centerVertical, layout_centerInParent are used for centering in a RelativeLayout.  To align to the sides you'd use layout_alignParentLeft, layout_alignParentRight, layout_alignParentTop and layout_alignParentBottom.